# Add additional divs to filtered portfolio

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to set up a filtered portfolio using a code I found on codepen. I was able to implement the code, but I was unsuccessful in adding additional code to apply a hover effect with the javascript function. What am I doing wrong? Here is the example: https://codepen.io/creotip/pen/dfjeF

```
$(function() {
    var selectedClass = "";
    $(".btn").click(function() {
        selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel"); 
        $("#portfolio").fadeTo(100, 0.1);
        $("#portfolio div").not("." + selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('scale-anm');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("." + selectedClass).fadeIn().addClass('scale-anm');
            $("#portfolio").fadeTo(300, 1);
        }, 300); 
    });
});
```

I want to apply the two divs (overlay and text) to the javascript code but I don't know how:

```
<div id="portfolio">
    <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
        <img src="{image:Post1}" width="100%"/>
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">
                 Hello World <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>

[...]
</div>
```

Comment: you want to insert the overlay block dynamically on load or you want to make a slide effect of the overlay block when hover the tile block?

Take a look at this pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KWWLLO - is this the one you are expecting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just CSS by adding the `.overlay` to your markup inside of the `.tile` divs, hide the overlay by default, and trigger it to display in CSS with `.tile:hover .overlay`.

I've added an overlay to the first image in your portfolio as an example.

```js
$(function() {
  var selectedClass = "";
  $(".fil-cat").click(function() {
    selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel");
    $("#portfolio").fadeTo(100, 0.1);
    $(".tile").not("." + selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('scale-anm');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("." + selectedClass).fadeIn().addClass('scale-anm');
      $("#portfolio").fadeTo(300, 1);
    }, 300);

  });
});
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 900px;
  float: none;
  margin: auto;
}

#portfolio {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1rem;
  -moz-column-gap: 1rem;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  -webkit-column-width: 33.33333333333333%;
  -moz-column-width: 33.33333333333333%;
  column-width: 33.33333333333333%;
}

.tile {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease;
  transition: all 350ms ease;
}

.tile:hover {}

.scale-anm {
  transform: scale(1);
}

p {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px #ccc dotted;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: lato;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

p:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #333;
  color: #eee;
}

.tile img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.btn {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: normal;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  color: #555;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.btn:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: var(--darken-2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px var(--darken-3);
}

::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.tile:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://npmcdn.com/basscss@8.0.0/css/basscss.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="toolbar mb2 mt2">
  <button class="btn fil-cat" href="" data-rel="all">All</button>
  <button class="btn fil-cat" data-rel="web">Websites</button>
  <button class="btn fil-cat" data-rel="flyers">Flyers</button>
  <button class="btn fil-cat" data-rel="bcards">Business Cards</button>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="portfolio">
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
    <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/2-mon_1092-300x234.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">
                 Hello World <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm bcards all">
    <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/jti-icons_08-300x172.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
    <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/emi_haze-300x201.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
    <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/codystretch-300x270.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm flyers all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97190&w=350&h=190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm bcards all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97290&w=200&h=290" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm flyers all">
    <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/jti-icons_08-300x172.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm flyers all">
    <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/transmission_01-300x300.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97290&w=200&h=290" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm flyers all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97290&w=200&h=290" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
    <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/the-ninetys-brand_02-300x300.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm bcards all">
    <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/15-dia_1092-1-300x300.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97190&w=350&h=190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm bcards all">
    <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/emi_haze-300x201.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
    <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/transmission_01-300x300.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97190&w=350&h=190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm bcards all">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97290&w=200&h=290" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: I have it implemented this way, but with the javascript code when you select a portfolio category doesn't display the overlay anymore.

Comment: @blandz ah. in the javascript, changed  `$("#portfolio div").not("." + selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('scale-anm');` to `$(".tile").not("." + selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('scale-anm');` how about now?